Designing Tables for Large Amounts of Time-Series Data
I'm designing a Postgres table to store large amounts of time series data and I'm trying to figure out the best way to structure the columns. I've looked at answers such as this one, but since it's almost 10 years old I wanted to see if there are any new things I should be aware of.
The time series data comes from many sources (that's what src_id in the examples refers to). Each source will have one data point per minute, and each data point has many different measurements. The measurements represent things such as temperature, humidity, etc. for that specific minute. I've abstracted them to just be "measurement A",  "measurement B", and so on for the examples though. There are currently 20 measurement types that need to be supported, with more being added in the future.
The amount of data is in the billions of rows. The vast majority of writes will be adding new rows for the current minute. Typical read queries will be for a specific source, time window, and measurement type. I'm also planning on partitioning whatever table I choose, perhaps into month-long partitions.
Option 1) Flat table
I could implement a simple flat table. One drawback is that as I add more measurement types over time, I will have to update the table with new columns. It's also starting with 23 columns which seems like I'm going down the wrong path.
TABLE data_points (id, src_id, timestamp          , measurement_a, measurement_b, ...)
                  (1 , 1     , 2024-01-01 00:00:00, 100          , 6.8          , ...)
                  (2 , 2     , 2024-01-01 00:00:00, 55           , 0.1          , ...)

Option 2) Key-value pairs
This reduces the number of columns to a set amount, so I will not have to update the table with new columns as new measurements are added. However there will many more rows (20x to start with, since I'm starting with 20 measurement types).
TABLE data_points (id, src_id, timestamp          , meas_type, meas_value)
                  (1 , 1     , 2024-01-01 00:00:00, A        , 100       )
                  (2 , 1     , 2024-01-01 00:00:00, B        , 6.8       )
                  ... 

                  (3 , 2     , 2024-01-01 00:00:00, A        , 55        )
                  (4 , 2     , 2024-01-01 00:00:00, B        , 0.1       )
                  ... 

Option 3) Two tables
I could have one table store the src_id and timestamp, and the other table store the measurement data. This is similar to the key-value pairs, just split over two tables so I don't have to repeat the src_id and timestamp columns as much.
This might make partitioning a bit trickier though. Also all reads would have to do a join, and I care more about performance than overall db size, so maybe it's not worth the overhead?
TABLE data_point_times (id, src_id, timestamp          )
                       (1 , 1     , 2024-01-01 00:00:00)
                       (2 , 1     , 2024-01-01 00:00:00)
                  
TABLE data_point_values (id, data_point_time_id, meas_type, meas_value)
                        (1 , 1                 , A        , 100       )
                        (2 , 1                 , B        , 6.8       )
                        ...
                        
                        (3 , 2                 , A        , 55       )
                        (4 , 2                 , B        , 0.1       )
                        ...

Option 4) jsonb
I could get "the best of both worlds" using jsonb; a static number of columns with fewer rows. But maybe this has drawbacks I'm not aware of?
TABLE data_points (id, src_id, timestamp          , data                                 )
                  (1 , 1     , 2024-01-01 00:00:00, {"measurement_a": 100, "measurement_b": 6.8, ... })
                  (2 , 2     , 2024-01-01 00:00:00, {"measurement_a": 55 , "measurement_b": 0.1, ... })
                 

Any help is greatly appreciated!

One word: TimescaleDB!

It depends on what you plan to do with the data.
20 measurements is not a lot of columns to be honest. 1 reading per minute is not that much, and billions of rows in a table isn't something to be afraid of any more than hundreds of rows (coming from someone who has worked with tables that large). In fact 1 reading per minute is only 500,000 rows per year per device. So you'd have to have at least 2,000 devices running simultaneously to achieve the billions of rows you mentioned, in a year's time.
Option 1
In any case, a regular "flat" table can handle rows on that order of magnitude just fine, even into the trillions of rows.
If your use cases involve a mix of manipulating, calculating, or aggregating some of the measurements you plan to store, then I'd lean to Option 1 since it'll give you the most flexibility to query the measurements in their native data types. It also allows the database system to create appropriate statistics based on the data of those columns individually and their types, which helps the query planner make better decisions when coming up with an efficient query plan to execute said queries.
There are multiple ways of minimal hassle to handle changing the schema of the table as, for example, new measurements are added.
Option 4
If you plan to just use the database to store the data as is, and retrieve it as is, to just display it somewhere else, then this may be a fine option too. The advantage it has over Option 1, is you don't have to really manage any schema changes as more measurements are added, etc. (Though it really is pretty simple to manage in Option 1, so IMO, that's not really a concern.)
There may be some negligible overhead of boxing and unboxing the JSON, but depending on how many rows you retrieve at a time, and how you consume them, it likely wouldn't matter.
Option 2
Unlike what bobflux recommended, I would not attempt to store key-value pairs in a RDBMS, which is not a key-value store. That would be denormalized and have drawbacks such as improper statistics which can affect performance, and making it more difficult to query should you need to manipulate, calculate, or aggregate over the data.
I don't see a need to consider this option at all, but if you do end up wanting to go this route, then please switch to a key-value store database system specifically, at least, so you can benefit from a database engine designed to handle that structure.

I went with option 1. In my tests, I found that option 4 (jsonb) had significant overhead due to type casting. See here for more info.

@Robert Yes, that makes sense. You were manipulating the JSONB column (implicitly, in order to unbox, so it can be joined to) which will always have a measurable performance overhead (as I mentioned). Good test though. Cheers!

I will use MQTT terms: "topic" represents the unique identifier  of the sensor (for example src_id, measurement_id), "timestamp" obviously, and "value" is the measurement itself.

Typical read queries will be for a specific source, time window, and measurement type.

As usual with time series I assume you will want to plot your data, do reports, and compute aggregates for the value of one sensor over a time period. The best way (in fact, the only way) to make this fast is to have good locality of reference, that is to organize the table on disk as ordered by (topic, timestamp).
When this is done, retrieving rows WHERE topic=... AND timestamp BETWEEN ... AND ... ORDER BY timestamp

Requires only sequential reads, no random reads all over the place to grab each row

Does not require sorting as the rows are already in the requested order


Option 1: Flat table would be a maintenance nightmare, especially if you add new sources with different measurement types from the others.
Option 2: key value pairs is the classic way to do it, that's how everyone does it, mostly because it works.
Postgres doesn't implement automatic clustered tables, but it has index only scans, so the postgres solution is to use a covering index on (topic, timestamp, value) which will be organized in the proper order and fulfill the requirements. Queries described above will be quick index only scans, and the table itself will probably never be read.
Option 3: two tables does not allow clustering of the data by (topic, timestamp) so it will require random reads when fetching timestamp ranges, it will be slow.
Option 4: jsonb could perhaps be useful. If the spirit is to pack the rows into jsonb to save space, you could also use hstore instead. To go all the way you should use the shortest possible keys, stored in a separate table so "measurement_a" becomes just something like "1". This can't be enforced with a foreign key. Drawbacks are jsonb is a bit slower, and it needs to read data for all measurements even if you need just one, but the total table size will be smaller. I'd say "meh" on this one.
Note you do not need a separate primary key: (topic, timestamp) is unique and not null so it can be a useful primary key. Unless you want to allow two different measurements with the same (topic,timestamp) but that would be a bit surprising.
So I would go with option 2 with covering index.
MySQL/InnoDB or another database that supports index-organized tables would halve the storage requirement, as it does not need to store the table and the index, because the index is the table.
I would also recommend trying a database specialized in time series. There are several. The one I'm using is Clickhouse, so I won't comment on others.
The idea is that, if you drop features you don't actually need in the context of time series like updates, transactions, etc, you can get much lower overhead.
Drawbacks:

Do not ever attempt OLTP workloads on these databases
A bit quirky
Query optimizer often not as smart as Postgres

Advantages:

Index organized table stores rows in the proper order, which solves the locality of reference problem

Columnar storage puts all values for one columns in the same place, which enables pretty good data compression.


For example, topics are stored in order, which results in long sequences of the same value, which compress to near nothing. Timestamps are monotonous increasing, so delta compression works well. If values are not noisy you will often get long constant sequences too. On my time series data I get about 11x compression, that's about 1 byte per row of storage. Thus, more of the table fits in cache.

Efficient access

A query like "max(value) for each day" on a topic with 200M rows in the 2.2 billion row table takes 1.5 seconds. This is very useful for plotting. If it is too slow, it also supports automatic aggregating materialized views.

ASOF JOINs, which you don't know you need, but you will.


"Option 1: Flat table would be a maintenance nightmare" - Disagree, having worked with tables in the 10s of billions of rows. "Option 2: key value pairs is the classic way to do it, that's how everyone does it" - Also disagree. It depends on what the use cases are for the data. If it's a mix of aggregative and non-aggregative measurements then stuffing those together in the same column makes it more difficult (and potentially less efficient) to query. It also makes it harder for the optimizer to create proper statistics for in a traditional RDBMS, which shouldn't be used for KVP.

Option 1: Flat table would be a maintenance nightmare, especially if you add new sources with different measurement types from the others.: why? On the contrary, having per-metric distinct columns is the option that allows a precise choice of data type per metric, which the other options do not allow. If you have to use a general-purpose RDBMS like Postgres for that, at least profit from what it's good at.

I recommend option 1.
The problem with option 2 is that each table row in PostgreSQL has an overhead of at least 23 bytes apart from the data, so the tables will become much bigger.
Option 3 is possibly worse that option 2. src_id and timestamp are small, so you won't benefit much over option 2, as far as storage space is concerned.
Option 4 is a solution you can consider if you have hundreds of measurements.
